# PostgreSQL, SELECT CASE COALESCE

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, aggregate

I need to 'name' categories: `mycat` is a `text` column with possible values `'0'` to `'4'`.

```
SELECT CASE mycat                                       
       WHEN '0' THEN 'ZERO'                         
       WHEN '1' THEN 'ONE'                      
       WHEN '2' THEN 'TWO'                      
       WHEN '3' THEN 'THREE'                        
       WHEN '4' THEN 'OTHER'        
   END AS my_category,
   COALESCE(SUM(col1), 0), 
   COALESCE(SUM(col2), 0), 
   COALESCE(SUM(col3), 0) 
   FROM mytable 
GROUP BY mycat 
ORDER BY mycat;
```

That works OK, but I have some an error in my program which very rarely writes `null` (or `''` as I can see in pgAdmin). In such cases I have to treat that `''` the same as `'0'`.
But I can't get that!

I try like this:

```
SELECT CASE COALESCE(mycat, '0')
```

But this doesn't solve it at all.
How to get that `''` will be summed and grouped together with `'0'` category?

PostgreSQL 9.3, Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use COALESCE in the `group by` and `order by` also similar to how you planned to change the `case` expression, but postgres is giving error , so another option is to wrap your statement in a subquery and do `group by`

```
SELECT my_category, 
       COALESCE(SUM(col1), 0), 
       COALESCE(SUM(col2), 0), 
       COALESCE(SUM(col3), 0) 
FROM
(
SELECT CASE coalesce(mycat ,'0')                                     
       WHEN '0' THEN 'ZERO'                         
       WHEN '1' THEN 'ONE'                      
       WHEN '2' THEN 'TWO'                      
       WHEN '3' THEN 'THREE'                        
       WHEN '4' THEN 'OTHER' 
       WHEN '' THEN 'ZERO'       
   END AS my_category,
   col1,
   col2,
   col3
   FROM mytable 
) T
GROUP BY my_category
ORDER BY my_category
```

Comment: Hi radar, that don't work: ERROR:  column "mytable.mycat" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT CASE coalesce(mycat, '0'). What do I do wrong?

Comment: @user973238, it was strange postgre is giving error, so another option is to wrap in subquery. updated the answer.

Comment: That don't sum '0' and '' category. If I add ELSE 'ZERO' after 'OTHER' then sum's it.

Comment: @user973238, i see that it is summing the val. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5c8ab/5

Comment: I see. Then maybe my value is not null? It is expressed like '' in pgAdmin.

Comment: @user973238, you can a condition for that too. updated.

Comment: I strongly recommend to add in your script the ELSE for eventually future not wanted data.

Comment: ["postgre" is not an accepted abbreviation for Postgres.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Answer (score 3):

You can have this without subquery. You could repeat the expression in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause. But it's **much simpler** to use the ordinal number of the output column instead:

```sql
SELECT CASE mycat
         WHEN '1' THEN 'ONE'
         WHEN '2' THEN 'TWO'
         WHEN '3' THEN 'THREE'
         WHEN '4' THEN 'OTHER'
         ELSE          'ZERO'  -- catches all other values
       END AS my_category
    ,  COALESCE(SUM(col1), 0) AS sum1
    ,  COALESCE(SUM(col2), 0) AS sum2
    ,  COALESCE(SUM(col3), 0) AS sum3
FROM   mytable 
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

I chose the **simplest and fastest** code. The ELSE branch catches `0`, `''` and `NULL` - or any other value not yet filtered! But you say there are no others.

#### A couple of rants:

> `mycat` is 'text' column with possible values '0' to '4'.

This is wrong in two ways.

1. Obviously, there are empty strings (`''`) and / or `NULL` values, too.
2. With that fixed, [`integer`, `smallint`, of `"char"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) with a `CHECK` cnstraint would be sensible choices for the data type. (Maybe even [`enum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html).) [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html), not so much.

To find out your actual range of values:

```
SELECT mycat, count(*) AS ct
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC;
```

If your client obfuscates NULL and empty values, test with `mycat IS NULL`. You *need* to know and understand the difference in many situations.

This orders by the resulting text in `my_category` like: `ONE, OTHER, THREE, TWO, ZERO`? I doubt you want that.